# Can't unpack a flat list in a customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I've been able to make a flat list unpacking a list of tuples using python like the following:

```
items = [('Brandon', 'WME', 'phone'), ('Brian', 'Endeavor', 'phone one'), ('Duncan', 'Entertainment', 'phone two')]
flat_list =  [i for elem in items for i in elem]
print(flat_list)
```

Output:

```
['Brandon', 'WME', 'phone', 'Brian', 'Endeavor', 'phone one', 'Duncan', 'Entertainment', 'phone two']
```

If I use asterisk like `print(*flat_list)`, the list becomes:

```
Brandon WME phone Brian Endeavor phone one Duncan Entertainment phone two
```

How can I make the list to be like the following?

```
Brandon, WME, phone, Brian, Endeavor, phone one, Duncan, Entertainment, phone two
```

Comment: Im not well versed in python but could you add a ", " inside the inner loop?

Comment: Look at [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: `print(*flat_list, sep=", ")`, although this just prints a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Example:

```
print(", ".join(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the strings with a delimiter:

```
>>> ", ".join(flat_list)
'Brandon, WME, phone, Brian, Endeavor, phone one, Duncan, Entertainment, phone two'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `sep` parameter of [print](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print):

```
items = [('Brandon', 'WME', 'phone'), ('Brian', 'Endeavor', 'phone one'), ('Duncan', 'Entertainment', 'phone two')]
flat_list = [i for elem in items for i in elem]
print(*flat_list, sep=", ")
```

**Output**

```
Brandon, WME, phone, Brian, Endeavor, phone one, Duncan, Entertainment, phone two
```

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use np.flatten() i'm not entirely sure.